# A question about submodules

Tags: linear-algebra

R is an unitarian ring and I is a set.

Let R^(I)={f:I->R|f function that has a finite support}.

Prove that supp(f+g) is included in supp(f) U supp(g) where supp(f)={x from I|f(x)!=0}.

Please,could you show me a way to solve it?I have no clue at this one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x \in \operatorname{Supp}(f + g)$, then $(f + g)(x) = f(x) + g(x) \neq 0$ which means $f(x) \neq 0$, equivalently, $x \in \operatorname{Supp}(f)$, or $g(x) \neq 0$, equivalently, $x \in \operatorname{Supp}(g)$, for if both are equal to zero, then there sum would be zero. By definition, $x$ is in the union of these two sets.